# sliding/bringing in form elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jquery but I'm having trouble finding a minimum working example to achieve what I want to do:

1. Selectively hide form fields but reveal those upon pressing "Next" button.
2. Have a minimum simple implementation - something that works but minimal complexity.
3. Load forms components in from the left/right.
4. I don't mind how new form elements are brought it, so long as they over-write the existing form elements upon next.
5. I.e. I have 5 sets of fields of them such that clicking "Next" will cycle through all those div element or sets of fields.

Are there are suggestions or tutorials for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/BTsL3/8/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 1;
    $(".button1").click(function(){
        if(counter != 5)
        {
            $( ".form" + counter ).slideUp();
            counter++;
            $( ".form" + counter ).slideDown();
        }
        else
        {
            $( ".form" + counter ).slideUp();
            counter = counter - 4;
            $( ".form" + counter ).slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool That's great - is there a way I might be able to loop through N <div class="form1"> elements. I.e. I have 5 of them such that clicking "Next" will cycle through all those div elements.

Comment: Thanks. Ideally the first section should be shown on load and on clicking, second second should load but take over the first. I need to use one from though - so how do I adapt this to using <div> tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot - good basis that I can adapt. You've popped my Jquery cherry! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a Fiddle to really make it come in from the left, and for the form and 'adding' new.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ccb3/)

Stack makes me throw in some code, so this is a snippet, full code is in the fiddle.

```
$("#myform").animate({ left: '0'}, 600, function() {
    $(".thrown").animate({ left: '0'}, 900);
});
```

--Edit--

If you want to go in from the right, in the CSS, change the left: value from -2500 to 2500... that will force it to start at the right side of the page (still hidden) and go to the final location of left:0;